# I have a C# WinUI 3 app on the Microsoft Store. In the Partner Center I am showing crashes, but they shown as "Unknown". How can I debug?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, crash, winui-3

See the screenshot. All of my current crashes show "Unknown" in the Microsoft Developer Dashboard under the Health section. When I click it, I'm offered no info to help with debugging the issue.

How can I detect these crashes? Are there any third-party crash detection SDK's that do a better job that work for C# WinUI 3 apps?

Right now I'm just guessing as to what could be wrong. The app has a huge codebase, so I need SOMETHING to go off of here...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm that these are from the "store app users"; and not from something on your desktop. In the case of UWP, "my" failures show up in the store; it's the timeline that tells me they're mine. (The store wants to install my store apps on my machine; even though I "publish" from my machine).

In any event, I use "try ... catch" where appropriate, log all errors and give the user the option to "send" an error report (in cases where it is needed).